# How to set specific jdk version for active mq 5.12

Tags: java, configuration, activemq-classic

I have active mq running on my server. I wanted to upgrade to version 5.12, and check the documentation, but there states that I should change my JAVA_HOME env path.

The problem is that I can not change my JAVA_HOME setup, as other systems depend on the old JRE 1.6 version being set there. Is there any way to configure the jre/jdk version that active mq will use when running besides changing the global JAVA_HOME?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried writing a script. Basically in the script you will set Java Home path and make call to the jre/jdk. This has been regular use case for environments having multiple versions of jdk installed over the machine.  Could you please tell me what have you tried and which OS you are trying to do this

Comment: We already created a script, but we were surprised activemq would not bring already something in it's configuration files or scripts, as this use case seems to be very common to me. We also changed the PATH variable in the script to make the call to activemq cleaner

Comment: That is a very good point Marcelo, but it seems you did not check the activemq and env scripts. What you are refering to be not there is already present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a script to export the specific java you wanna use and call the java command

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk/jdk1.6.0_35
>
> $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar activemq

you will also need to define classpath variable to load the dependency jar.

Remember java is the execution command. And by exporting a specific java you are basically forcing the execution of your app through this java

-- New update. I should have thought of this earlier. In activemq there are two scripts in the bin named

> activemq -- this is the script you would be executing to run activemq in standalone mode

and

> env  -- this is the script containing environment settings including JAVA_HOME
>
> Note from the activemq script 
>   System variables for this script, like ACTIVEMQ_OPTS and ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY,
>   can be configured in 'env' script located in this directory.
>   "this directory" refers to the bin directory

set the JAVA_HOME in env to your specific version of JAVA_HOME. You will find this environment variable in the last line of the script

Comment: Hi, sure that is an option, but I am very surprised that activemq has no such a parameter in its configuration files, as I think my use case is very common and that would be the best solution.

Comment: We added these 2 lines to our script, also including the PATH, to make the call to activemq cleaner and set everything  to java 8: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25` `export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/r‌​uby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/‌​rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/u‌​sr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/bin.`